# Lawyer submitted my PERM for a location based position. But now they're telling me a new my PERM is necessary because I'm working remotely

Tags: usa, greencard, work-permit

After 14 months my PERM Labor certification got approved.

Before getting my PERM approved, I've moved out from where company's office is located (NY) to work remote (from FL). Lawyer said it would not be a problem.

But now, my company's new immigration counsel are telling me that they'll need to redo my PERM (I guess it means start over) since I plan to continue working remotely.

1. Does anyone have experience relocating while PERM is being processed?
2. Is there any option to keep the PERM without returning to job's location?
3. What would happen if green card is approved, but I don't return to the job's location? What are the consequences for employee and employer?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any option to keep the PERM without returning to job's location?

No. Job site location is part of the [PERM application](https://www.dol.gov/sites/dolgov/files/ETA/oflc/pdfs/9089form.pdf) (see part H), and is also a parameter in the determination of the prevailing wage (part F).

> What would happen if green card is approved, but I don't return to job's location? What are the consequences for employee and employer?

What are the consequences of fraudulently getting a green card? It would be taken away of course, and very likely never given again.

> Lawyer said it would not be a problem.
>
> But now, my company's new immigration counsel are telling me that they'll need to redo my PERM

Now you know why the company has a new immigration counsel.